# Redux state's nested object is available but unaccessible within component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

enter code hereI'm providing Redux Global State to my whole react app through a Provider wrapper in my app.js file.

I've no problem accessing any other piece of state other than "Current Profile".

Here is the ***component***:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { loadTargetProfiles, loadCurrentProfile  } from "../../actions/profile";

const Friends = ({
  loadCurrentProfile,
  loadTargetProfiles,
  profile: { currentProfile, targetProfiles, targetProfilesAreLoading },
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    loadTargetProfiles();
    loadCurrentProfile();
  }, []);

  console.log(currentProfile);

  return (
     ...
};

Friends.propTypes = {
  loadTargetProfiles: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  loadCurrentProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  profile: state.profile,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  loadCurrentProfile,
  loadTargetProfiles,
})(Friends);
```

here is the loadCurrentProfile ***action*** responsible for providing the currentProfile piece of state.

```
export const loadCurrentProfile = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await api.get("/profile/current");

    dispatch({
      type: LOAD_CURRENT_PROFILE,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status },
    });
  }
};
```

here is the relevant part of the ***Reducer***

```
const initialState = {
  currentProfile: null,
  targetProfile: null,
  targetProfiles: [],
  currentProfileIsLoading: true,
  targetProfileIsLoading: true,
  targetProfilesAreLoading: true,
  error: {},
};

//
// Export Reducer
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case LOAD_CURRENT_PROFILE:
      return {
        ...state,
        currentProfile: payload,
        currentProfileIsLoading: false,
      };
```

here is the ***API*** that's getting hit:

```
router.get("/current", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const profile = await Profile.findOne({
      user: req.user.id,
    }).populate("user", ["_id", "username", "registerdate"]);

    if (!profile) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ msg: "There is no profile for this user." });
    }

    res.json(profile);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error...");
  }
});
```

here is the ***console***

[image]

here is the currentProfile piece of state expanded:

[image]

when i try to reach into the currentProfile piece of state, for example

```
  const Friends = ({
  loadCurrentProfile,
  loadTargetProfiles,
  profile: { currentProfile: {
    avatar
  }, targetProfiles, targetProfilesAreLoading },
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    loadTargetProfiles();
    loadCurrentProfile();
  }, []);

  console.log(avatar);
```

It give me the error:

***TypeError: Cannot read property 'avatar' of null***

here is Redux Dev Tools screenshot:

[image]

***Fix:***

I (temporarily) got rid of the error by accessing the inner state after declaring the function.

```
const Friends= ({
  profile: { currentProfileIsLoading },
  currentProfile,
}) => {
  currentProfile && console.log(currentProfile.avatar);
```

and it works for now but it certainly isn't the most elegant solution. Is there a way to add this guard in the function declaration in order to set the state in one place?

Comment: Are you using the redux thunk middleware? https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

Comment: The log at line 26 in `Friends` appears to be logging the `currentProfile` each time state updates and updates the mapped prop. What is the issue? Both `targetProfiles` and `targetProfilesAreLoading` are truthy values in your state, but `currentProfile` is null until the GET resolves. Is this not what you expect?

Comment: @PatrickHund Yes i'm using redux-thunk.

Comment: @Accretence it seems that you're trying to access `state.profile` in `mapStateToProps` whereas you've declared it as `currentProfile` in your reducer

Comment: @DrewReese yes but i can reach into deeper levels of state in other components with no problem, and they are all fetching their data from MongoDB, why does this particular piece of state give me this error? If the state is null at first ( which it should be ), then other components should give this error too.

Comment: "state" isn't null, just `currentProfile` is. Are these other components access *this* same piece of state and working as expected?

Comment: @HMR I added a screenshot to the post, GET_CURRENT_PROFILE only get's called once and there doesn't seem to be any problems there.

Comment: @DrewReese No they are not, they are accessing other pieces of state such as targetProfiles and they seem to be working fine. The exact problem i'm having is accessing nested objects inside currentProfile.

Comment: Yes, please refer back to my initial comment about `currentProfile` being null until the fetch resolves while the other two properties *are* defined. You can't access `X` of null. Updated my answer to point this out a little more overtly.

Comment: @HMR I updated the question to try and include the exact piece of code that causes the error.

Comment: @Accretence It's been asked a couple of times already but you obviously not guarding access to `currentProfile` and trying to access `currentProfile.avatar` before it's been set. With the code in your question you now have 2 Friends components and the one you added last won't ever console.log because it'll error before it has a chance to (accessing currentProfile.avatar would throw causing no console.log to be possible). Without a reproducible example it would be impossible to determine what guard you are missing but the error is clear, you're accessing a property that doesn't exist.

Comment: @HMR thank you for your thorough explanation, I completely understand the situation right know and I'm trying to workout where to put these guards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue:** Both `targetProfiles` and `targetProfilesAreLoading` are truthy values in your state, but `currentProfile` is null until the GET resolves. You can't access the `avatar` property of a null object.

You can provide some default argument value for `profile`, this only works really though if `profile` is undefined, null counts as a defined value.

```
const Friends = ({
  loadCurrentProfile,
  loadTargetProfiles,
  profile: {
    currentProfile = {},
    targetProfiles,
    targetProfilesAreLoading
  },
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    loadTargetProfiles();
    loadCurrentProfile();
  }, []);

  console.log(currentProfile);

  return (
     ...
};
```

You can also use a guard on the possibly undefined/null object

```
currentProfile && currentProfile.avatar
```

Another alternative is to use a state selector library like [`reselect`](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) that allows you to pull/augment/derive/etc... state values that get passed as props. This also allows you to set default/fallback values for state. It pairs with redux nicely.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer, I managed to get rid of the error with a temporary solution and updated the question.